# How to use MPVolume View correctly?

Tags: ios, xcode, mpvolumeview

[image: After implementing DonMag's answer, work's great]
[image: After implementing DonMag's answer, work's great]

-This was my Question: This is an audio player, I removed all the other lines for you to be easy in reading. The problem is in MPVolumeView. When user swipes all the way to maximum the button of the slider hovers over the connectivity button. When user swipes the button of the slider all the way to minimum the button of the slider doesn't move to the end.

-Dear DonMag, I am really thankful to you, It works! and HOW! I am adding screenshots. I believe your answer will be helpful to a lot of self tights.

[image: When user swipes the button of the slider all the way to minimum the button of the slider doesn't move to the end.]

[image: When user swipes all the way to maximum the button of the slider hovers over the connectivity button.]

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

class AudioPlayerViewControllerQ1: UIViewController {
      
   
@IBOutlet var holder: UIView!


    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
                
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        
        if holder.subviews.count == 0 {
        }
        
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 20,
                                                    y: holder.frame.size.height - 80,
                                                    width: holder.frame.size.width-40,
                                                    height: 30))
        
        holder.addSubview(volumeView)
        
    }

    private func setupView() {
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            holder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            holder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            holder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            holder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }
        
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the `MPVolumeView` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`? And why are you giving it a frame instead of using auto-layout constraints?

Comment: Oh I see, will try and comeback.

Comment: Hmm... `MPVolumeView` appears to be rather buggy. So ignore my comment about auto-layout. See my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: **Dear friend, your answer worked great. Thank you that you did not hesitate to work on this issue and answer. I really appreciate it.** I used ` .frame = CGRect ` to layout the other buttons in my audio player. can I use cgrect to layout container that contains volume views as well?

Comment: sure, you can do all of your layout by explicitly setting the frames with `CGRect`. I would ***strongly suggest***, though, that you learn and start using auto-layout constraints. It make it much, much, much easier to get your layout to automatically adapt to different screen sizes. See the **Edit** in my answer.

Comment: @DonMag **Dear Friend, I finally finished implementing auto-layout constraints in my project, Just need to say it is much more easier and developer friendly way. Thank you so much!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quick research and experimentation -- it appears `MPVolumeView` is rather buggy :(

When instantiated, if the current device volume is greater than `0`, the thumb will be offset on the x-axis. The higher the volume, the larger the offset.

Also, it doesn't play well at all with auto-layout constraints.

We can get around this by subclassing `MPVolumeView` and "fixing" the slider rect:

```
class MyVolumeView: MPVolumeView {
    override func volumeSliderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // this will avoid the thumb x-offset issue
        //  while keeping the route button vertically aligned
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 12.0, dy: 0.0).offsetBy(dx: -12.0, dy: -5.0)
    }
}
```

Then, to correct the problems with the vertical layout, we will want to offset the Y position when we set its frame.

Here's a quick example of one way to do that. I've embedded `MyVolumeView` in a "container" view, and used a property observer to update the frame whenever the container view's bounds changes:

```
class AudioPlayerViewControllerQ1: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // let's give the view a background color so we can easily see its frame
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // assuming "holder" view has buttons and other controls
        //  along with the MyVolumeView near the bottom
        let holder = UIView()
        holder.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        holder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(holder)
        
        // create a separate "container" view for the MyVolumeView
        let volumeViewContainer = UIView()
        // we'll make it red for now so we can see it
        volumeViewContainer.backgroundColor = .red
        volumeViewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(volumeViewContainer)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // let's make the holder 20-points inset on leading/trailing
            holder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            holder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // holder height (for this example) is 240.0
            holder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            // let's put its bottom 60-points from the bottom (of the safe area)
            holder.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -160.0),

            // volume view container leading/trailing equal to holder
            volumeViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            volumeViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // volume view container bottom equal to holder bottom
            volumeViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // volume view container height equal to 30-points
            volumeViewContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),

        ])

        // now we'll add a MPVolumeView to the container
        let v = MyVolumeView()
        volumeViewContainer.addSubview(v)

        // we'll use a property observer to update the MyVolumeView frame
        //  whenever the container bounds changes
        volumeViewContainer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", context: nil)

    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "bounds" {
            // make sure we're getting notified of the MyVolumeView container view
            if let cv = object as? UIView,
               let mpv = cv.subviews.first as? MyVolumeView {
                // set MyVolumeView frame to container view's bounds
                // and offset its y-position by 4-points (because of its buggy layout)
                mpv.frame = cv.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: 4.0)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It looks like this when running:

[image]

and we can drag the thumb all the way to the left:

[image]

and to the right (without overlapping the route button):

[image]

---

**Edit**

Here are a couple simplified examples...

Using `CGRect` frames instead of constraints (as requested by the OP):

```
class AudioPlayerViewControllerQ1: UIViewController {

    let holder = UIView()
    let myVolumeView = MyVolumeView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // let's give the view a background color so we can easily see its frame
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // assuming "holder" view has buttons and other controls
        //  along with the MPVolumeView near the bottom
        holder.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        view.addSubview(holder)
        
        // now we'll add a MPVolumeView to the container
        holder.addSubview(myVolumeView)

    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // let's make sure this only executes if the holder view frame has not been set yet
        if holder.frame.width != 320.0 {
            // set holder view frame to 320 x 240
            holder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320.0, height: 240.0)
            // center it in the view
            holder.center = view.center
            // set myVolumeView frame to same width as holder view
            //  30-points height, at bottom of holder view
            myVolumeView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: holder.frame.height - 30.0, width: holder.frame.width, height: 30.0)
        }
        
    }

}
```

and, this one using constraints:

```
class AudioPlayerViewControllerQ1: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // let's give the view a background color so we can easily see its frame
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        // assuming "holder" view has buttons and other controls
        //  along with the MPVolumeView near the bottom
        let holder = UIView()
        holder.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        holder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(holder)
        
        // now we'll add a MPVolumeView to the container
        let myVolumeView = MyVolumeView()
        myVolumeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        holder.addSubview(myVolumeView)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // set holder view frame to 320 x 240
            holder.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0),
            holder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            // center it
            holder.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            holder.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            // constrain myVolumeView leading/trailing/bottom equal to holder view
            myVolumeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myVolumeView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myVolumeView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holder.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            // myVolumeView height
            myVolumeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),

        ])
        
    }
    
}
```